# Computer restarts repeatedly after BIOS/Motherboard screen

Tags: windows-8, boot, hardware-failure, reboot

Every morning I turn on my computer—which is relatively new—and I never had any issue with it until now. It starts booting, shows that very first screen which has some motherboard picture, then it show which buttons to press to enter BIOS and etc… Then it restarts over and over again every 3-5 seconds.

What could it be?

I unplugged the power cable, checked all the cables, moved the case, it had some wires stuck under it, blew some dust—but didn’t open the case yet—and I tried to boot again and it booted successfully and I am writing this issue now.

My specs:

- **CPU:** i3-3220 3.30Ghz
- **RAM:** 8GB DDR3 RAM
- **HDD:** 1TB HDD
- **GPU:** GeForce GTX 650
- **OS:** Windows 8 x64

Also the most recent thing I did was upgrade my security software such as ZoneAlarm firewall, Comodo Antivirus and Spybot Search & Destroy. But maybe it doesn’t have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe a couple of reasons.  The first that I would check is the RAM.  If you have 2 modules, try taking one out, starting the PC.  If this happens again, swop the 2, same procedure again.  If this still happens, then you may have Powersupply issues.  Try swopping out the power supply with another one.  With the PC restart so fast after start up, I don't think it is not software as the computer does not get to the operating system during booting.

As suggested by AntonyLee:
Try running a diagnostic test from the BIOS if it is supported.

Comment: precise and correct. add one more points, if it is possible, try to enter the bios and perform memory diagnostic if it support.

Comment: @AntonyLee. Agree.  Only problem is if it is caused by the powersupply then it will restart during diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing each device one by one you think is problem and restarting the PC see if it makes any difference. Configure BIOS setting to standard, check CPU fan, heat sink and thermal paste.